# Printing user input in Java?

Tags: java, println

Say I had the Scanner method, and I want to print the user input after that.

Take this code for instance:

```
    String randomWords;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter two words separated: ");

    randomWords = kb.next();    
    System.out.println(randomWords);
```

And if the two separated words entered were

```
hello world
```

Only

```
hello
```

is printed

Why is this? and how can I print both of the words with the space included?

Thank you.

Comment: Read JavaDoc: [`Scanner#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**Scanner#nextLine(**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)) instead,

> This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line
>   separator at the end.

```
randomWords = kb.nextLine();
```

[**Scanner#next()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) reads the next complete token basing on the delimiter.

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern

As default delimiter of the scanner is **whitespace**, you should explicitly define the delimiter for your scanner using [**Scanner#useDelimiter(str)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29).
If you use `\n` next line as delimiter your curretn code would work.

```
 Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
    System.out.print("Please enter two words separated: "); 
    randomWords = kb.next();    
    System.out.println(randomWords);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Scanner.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method to read up to the line break (noninclusive).

```
randomWords = kb.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String randomWords;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter two words separated: ");

        randomWords = kb.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println(randomWords);
    }
```